# compiling libvirt on debian

Tags: debian, libvirt

When I complie libvirt on debian, it ask for libnl.

So I installed the libnl and libnl-dev.

But when i run *./configure* again, it says:

> configure: error:
>
> libnl-devel >= 1.1 is required for macvtap support**

I am sure of the existence of that lib:

```
root@d509706c202e:/usr/wch/full/libvirt-3.1.0# dpkg -l libnl-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
(...something omitted)
ii  libnl-dev 1.1-7 amd64 development library and headers for libnl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why configure is complaining about missing libnl, but I'll point out that these days it is recommended to use libnl 3 instead of libnl 1. So try the libnl-3-dev package instead.

FYI if you go to https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libvirt0 and download the file libvirt_1.2.9-9+deb8u3.debian.tar.xz, the 'debian/control' file inside that archive gives the listed of recommended build pre-requisites to install on Debian systems.